# the number of digits

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If we  divide the number $111222333444555666777888999$ by $111$.In which way one can find the number of digits of the result

Comment: will this help: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=111222333444555666777888999%2F111&t=crmtb01

Comment: Isn't it obviously 25?

Comment: 9 digits representing 1-9 and then 16 zeros for a total of 25 digits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$n=111222333444555666777888999>111000000000000000000000000$ so $\frac{n}{111}>1\cdot10^{24}$ which has 25 digits.

On the other hand, $111>100$, so $\frac{n}{111}<\frac{n}{100}$ which has 25 (non-fractional) digits.

All in all, the number of digits $d$ satisfies $25\le d \le 25$ so $d=25$.

Answer (score 2):

$111222333444555666777888999:111=1002003004005006007008009$

Answer (score 1):

Write $111222333444555666777888999$ as $\sum_{k=1}^9(10 - k) \times 111 \times 10^{3(k-1)}$ dividing by $111$ you get $\sum_{k=1}^9(10 - k) \times 10^{3(k-1)}$ and you get the largest value (the rest are smaller number, the sum does not change the number of digits) on this sum is $1 \times 10^{ 3 \times 8}$ that is $24$ zeros after $1$ which you get $25$.